# Weird wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having an issue with a method definition. I have this code in my "buy" model:

```
def update_amount newamount
    self.total_amount = self.total_amount +newamount
end
```

and this code at other place:

```
buy.update_amount(amount)
```

If I run the program, I get this error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
  app/models/buy.rb:18:in `update_amount'
```

Now, if I change for this (just to try):

```
buy.update_amount
```

I get this error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
      app/models/buy.rb:18:in `update_amount'
```

I'm new with Ruby on Rails so it's probably something easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def update_amount(newamount)
  self.total_amount += newamount
end
```

This adds the new amount to the current value of `total_amount` attribute.

You were trying to pass `newamount` as an argument to your `self.total_amount` attribute.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! i'll give you the correct answer in 10 mins

Comment: this is weird. i don't see any difference with the original code and this code.  it doesn't explain the error the OP is getting.

Comment: yep. look at toro2k's answer. it explains why the OP is getting the `wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)` error.  In other programming languages, having no space between the operators is fine so the original code is the same as your answer.  it just so happened that ruby interpreted `total_amount` as a method.

Answer (score 13):

Quite tricky error you have! The line:

```
self.total_amount = self.total_amount +newamount
```

Is interpreted by Ruby as:

```
self.total_amount = self.total_amount(+newamount)
```

Hence the you get the `ArgumentError`.

The Ruby lexer mistakes `+newamount` for a parameter (i.e. a unary plus followed by the `newamount` identifier) because it knows that `total_amount` is a method call, and the `+` is not followed by a space. Writing the line as:

```
self.total_amount = self.total_amount + newamount
```

Will fix the problem. Or better, use the `+=` shorthand as @backpackerhh suggested.